# Is KeyCloak authentication using Custom User Attribute possible?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

In KeyCloak, I want to add a new attribute for User, say Phone Number or MSISDN.
MSISDN will be added as a Custom attribute for a User.
Can I use this custom attribute as username to authenticate user on Login page? If it is possible, how can this be done?

Appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll probably have to write your own authentication SPI or user provider SPI to achieve this.
Once you have done this, you can configure the login function to take the custom attribute as of the username.